# C# WCF - ADO.NET Entity model - DbSet empty?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I created a new WCF project in visual studio based on a existing database.
I made two operations. One operation writes a record (createProfile) to the database and one retrieve data (GetProfiles). My project exists of 3 files: web.config, a edmx file and my svc class.

CreateProfile works fine, I checked in SQL and the record is created.
GetProfiles never gives a response. When I debug the context.UserProfileSet always counts 0 values.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

```
[DataContract]
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}




public class MusicOwnerService : IMusicOwnerService
{
    IEnumerable<UserProfile> GetProfiles()
    {
        using (MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities context = new MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities())
        {
            return context.UserProfileSet.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }


    public void CreateProfile()
    {
        using (MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities context = new MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities())
        {
            context.UserProfileSet.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = "John" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cant pass an IEnumerable object over the wire with WCF (unless youve a duplex binding of some sort??)..  so you would be  best to convert to a list and return that list like below:

```
List<UserProfile> GetProfiles()
    {
        using (MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities context = new MusicOwnerDatabaseEntities())
        {
            return context.UserProfileSet.ToList();
        }
    }
```